# Eval Tree in Scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala, reflection, eval

I'm trying to implement JSON-RPC server in Scala and want to mark my remote methods with annotations. Also it will be nice if method itself should not be worried about input parameters validation, so I want to put this validations inside annotation. I ended up with this:

```
class RPCMethod(validators: (String, PartialFunction[Any, Boolean])*) extends StaticAnnotation
```

And remote method is annotated like this:

```
@RPCMethod(
    "name" -> {
        case x: String => x == "Andrey"
    }
)
```

Now I'm trying to extract the {case ...} part and eval it to a function to check inbound value. But all I could get with reflection is a Tree:

```
val annotation = method.annotations.find(_.tree.tpe == typeOf[RPCMethod]).get
val validators = annotation.tree.children.tail
if (validators.isEmpty) {
    return true
} else {
    validators.head match {
        case q"scala.this.Predef.ArrowAssoc[$_](${name: String}).->[$_]($func)" => // Don't know how to eval 'func'
        case _ => throw some error
    }
}
```

So how can I get a valid function object from this Tree?

Comment: After adding scala-compiler to dependencies seems like this can be achieved using
`mirror.mkToolBox().eval(func)`
But now I have another problem. I need an actual Type of my RPC service class to reflect its methods. But when I try to run this piece of code:
`mirror.staticClass(x.getClass.getCanonicalName).selfType`
where x is an object of Class with annotated method with validations, I get an error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1 cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Names$Name`

Comment: And if I change PartialFunction to Function1:`@RPCMethod(
    "name" -> ((x: Any) => x == "Andrey")
  )` I get error: `ToolBoxError: reflective toolbox has failed: cannot operate on trees that are already typed` :(